# How do I list the table names in a SQFlite Database in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I have tried the following and only received information on the entire database.

```
listTables() async {
    sqflite.Database dbClient = await this.db;

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> tables = await dbClient
        .query('sqlite_master');

    print(tables);
  }
```

I am looking to get a list of the table names which exist in the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you see in the output, the schema is simple. `sqlite_master` table rows have `type = 'table'` and a `name` column.

Debug print:

```dart
(await db.query('sqlite_master', columns: ['type', 'name'])).forEach((row) {
  print(row.values);
});
```

to get something like:

```
(table, Product)
(table, Client)
(table, Request)
(index, Request_clientId)
(index, Request_productId)
```

You can get the table names with the following code:

```dart
var tableNames = (await db
        .query('sqlite_master', where: 'type = ?', whereArgs: ['table']))
    .map((row) => row['name'] as String)
    .toList(growable: false);
```